# Apple Push Notifications not coming into iPhone

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I am learning about FCM and sending push notifications. I used this [appCoda](https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/) article and the [firebase website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) to set mine up. So I am getting the success messages shown on the firebase website :

```
{
  "success": 2,
  "failure": 0
}
```

But the messages do not pop up on my phone. I also tried sending push notifications from the firebase console (as shown in the appcoda article) and they are delivered but do not come to my phone. I set up for the app to receive notifications so I am not sure where the disconnect is. What could I be doing wrong? I am open to any suggestions. 
It is not a duplicate because I already looked over that and it does not solve my question.

Comment: Are you checking it from `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)`?

Comment: I assumed that was for only when the application was in the foreground? I commented it out but I will re-add to see the difference